# CSS indent everything except headers

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, indentation

I have an html-document that is generated by an application. I want to indent everything in this document except the h2 headers. I've been playing around with the css :not selector but I can't quite get it to work the way I want.

Here is the css that I came up with and the jsfiddle that I've been using for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/xm71wr2a/

```
body :not(h2){
    margin-left: 20px
}
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle the p and the div are properly indented but the text between them is not. Is it possible to apply the indentation to that as well, or do I have to modify the html to achieve this? I have access to the application's source code so I can edit the output that it generates but I'd rather solve this using css if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you should give the not indented text a tag. It doesn't matter what tag, just not an H2-tag. CSS style will not apply without the text having a tag.

```
<h2>Not indented</h2>
<p>THIS SHOULD BE INDENTED</p>
<p>THIS SHOULD BE INDENTED</p>
<div>THIS SHOULD BE INDENTED</div>
<h2>Not indented</h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xm71wr2a/1/

Comment: Dang I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this because I would have to modify the application that generates the html and that could take a while. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

easy mistake to make, you just added an extra space between `body:` and `not`

it should be:

```
body:not(h2){
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

to elaborate on the previous answer, html text content like yours without at least a `<p>` tag will be very limited in its mutability from your css file especially when that is your only resource to manipulate that content.

wrapping the content you want indented in a `<p>` tag and leaving the `<h2>` tags around the content you don't want to indent will create the separation between the two, and allow you to manipulate them individually with css.

alternatively, a way to select ALL elements of a html page and apply the same css effect to them would be using the `*` selector:

`*:not(h2){
    margin-left: 20px
}`

`*` = all html DOM elements

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those do what I want. body:not(h2) indents everything, including the h2 headers and *:not(h2) somehow indents everything twice.

Also, doesn't "body :not(h2)" mean "Every element under body except h2" while "body:not(h2)" means "Every body element except the ones that contain h2 elements" ?